# How to create a Socket connection between Unity/C# Server and Android/Java Client?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an academic project that consists in controlling a simulated environment created in Unity3D, from a conventional Android application. I already created the scenario in Unity and the mobile application is completely finished, my problem is in the connection. I chose to use sockets because of its simplicity. I managed to connect the application to a server written in C # through conventional Sockets, I know that information can be sent, but when I implemented it in Unity, everything failed, so I decided to use TCP Listener instead of Sockets in Unity / C # (the client Android still uses a conventional TCP connection through Sockets), and in effect, the application connects but there is no information transfer, because the Unity console throws an error that says: `ObjectDisposedException: Can not access to disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient'.`(The error is presented in line number 56: `stream = client.tcp.GetStream ();`) The main objective is to obtain the flow of information that would be represented in something like: `"1: 0: 1: 0"` and being able to make a Split to that string and according to that value change the state of a light bulb or other element, nevertheless I need the essential thing: to establish the connection flow. I'm not an expert in C # and much less using Unity, I really do not know much about design, but I wanted to do it to deliver an innovative work, I hope someone can guide me.

PD: C# Socket (No Unity yet) server working with Android Java client:
![1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBdmW.jpg

//This is my Unity3D/C# Server:

```
public class SocketManager : MonoBehaviour
{
private List<ServerClient> connectedClients;
private List<ServerClient> disconectedClients;
private TcpListener server;
private string data;
private NetworkStream stream;
private StreamReader stremaReader;
private bool serverStarted;
public int socketPort = 7691;

private void Start()
{
    connectedClients = new List<ServerClient>();
    disconectedClients = new List<ServerClient>();
    try
    {
        server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.64"),        socketPort);
        server.Start();

        serverListening();
        serverStarted = true;
        Debug.Log("Server started. Port: " + socketPort.ToString());


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Server socket error: " + ex);
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if (!serverStarted)
        return;

    foreach (ServerClient client in connectedClients)
    {
        if (IsConnected(client.tcp))
        {
            client.tcp.Close();
            disconectedClients.Add(client);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            stream = client.tcp.GetStream();
            if (stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                this.stremaReader = new StreamReader(stream, true);
                data = stremaReader.ReadLine();

                if (data != null)
                    OnIcomingData(client, data);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void OnIcomingData(ServerClient client, string data)
{
    Debug.Log(client.clientName + ": " + data);
}

private bool IsConnected(TcpClient tcp)
{
    try
    {

        if (tcp != null && tcp.Client != null && tcp.Client.Connected)
        {
            if (tcp.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
            {
                return !(tcp.Client.Receive(new byte[1], SocketFlags.Peek) == 0);
            }

            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private void serverListening()
{
    server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptTcpClient, server);
}
private void AcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    TcpListener tcplistener = (TcpListener)asyncResult.AsyncState;
    connectedClients.Add(new ServerClient(tcplistener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult)));
    serverListening();
}

}

public class ServerClient
{

public TcpClient tcp;
public string clientName;

public ServerClient(TcpClient tcp)
{
    this.tcp = tcp;
    this.clientName = "Android";
}
}
```

// This is my Android/Java Client:

```
public class SocketThread extends Thread {

private Socket adviser;
private DataOutputStream dataOut;

@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    Log.e("Status:", "Thread started");
    try {
        adviser = new Socket("192.168.1.64", 7691);
        dataOut = new DataOutputStream(adviser.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void sendCommand(String text) {
    try {
        dataOut.writeUTF(text);
        Log.e("Sended Text: ", text);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: inside your foreach loop you got an if statement `if (IsConnected(client.tcp))`, and if its true (the client is connected) you close the connection by calling `client.tcp.Close();`. Is this intended? Or did you mean `!IsConnected`? and if the client is not connected (as it will in the next iteration because you closed the connection) you try to get the stream using `stream = client.tcp.GetStream();`, which isn't possible since the stream is closed. So i think doing `if (!IsConnected(client.tcp))` should do the trick?

Comment: remy_rm, yeah, you rigth, I'm very grateful for your help, I no longer have the error, however, I don't show the string that I'm sending from the mobile phone, I know that both devices are connected but the server is not getting the information, I'm doing a couple of checks through debugging. ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more detailed answer than my comment, for future reference.

The problem lies in the following if check `if (IsConnected(client.tcp))`.

Right now what is happening is that when the client is connected to the server (so the if returns `true`) you are Closing the connection using `client.tcp.Close();` and adding the connection to your `disconectedClients` list (But you are not removing the client from your `connectedClients` list! Meaning the client is now in both lists). Then when the next iteration of the foreach loop  `foreach (ServerClient client in connectedClients)` comes around the `if (IsConnected(client.tcp))` will return `false` (the client is no longer connected to the server, since you called `close()` in the previous iteration.

You then try to call `stream = client.tcp.GetStream();` on a stream that is already closed, resulting in an error telling you you cannot get the stream.

This should fix it:

```
if (IsConnected(client.tcp))
{
    client.tcp.Close();
    client.tcp.Dispose(); //Dispose of a stream to release it for GC
    disconectedClients.Add(client);
    connectedClients.Remove(client); //Note to also remove the disconnected client from the connectedClients list.
    continue;
}
else
{ ...rest of logic }
```

Note that i added `connectedClients.Remove(client);` and `client.tcp.Dispose(); to your logic closing the stream. If you don't do this it'll keep getting included in the`foreach`loop unnecessarily, and the programm will try to call`close()` on a connection that is already closed, resulting in more errors. Disposing of the stream will release it so the garbage collector can collect it, freeing up memory.